# ASP.NET Core WebApi with SQL Server and EFCore 2

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create my first .NET Core Web Api with SQL Server and Entity Framework Core 2, but when I call the endpoint from my browser while project build, I get nothing. It always stays at the startup page that says "Hello World".

How to get data from the Rest Api correctly?

First, my model class:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With a `DbContext`:

```
public class TaskManagerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TaskManagerDbContext(DbContextOptions<TaskManagerDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Then I hardcoded two records into database:

[image]

I generated `ProjectsController` by scaffolding an API with R/W based on Entity Framework. The `get` function look like this (I think there is no sense to show all controller because its generated by the scaffold):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TaskManagerDbContext _context;

    public ProjectsController(TaskManagerDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Projects
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects()
    {
        return _context.Projects;
    }

    // GET: api/Projects/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProject([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var project = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(id);

        if (project == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(project);
    }
}
```

Finally, my `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddDbContext<TaskManagerDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Question is, what change is needed to get data from my database by API endpoints? For now, when I try to call the endpoint, it always stays on the "hello world" page.

[image]

My connection string is in `appsettings.json` file in project directory.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Just post an answer i will mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some remnant left from the template for an empty asp core project.

Just remove this entire block, because you don't need it:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});
```